# Adding two data types in bytearrayoutputstream and printing it

Tags: java, arrays, bytearrayoutputstream

I have used the following code. I just can't seem to get the value of x back from the byte array.
Here is my code:

```
int seqNo = 0;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(bout);
    try {
        out.writeInt(seqNo);
        String i = Integer.toString(seqNo) + "hello";
        byte[] b = i.getBytes();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
        int x = b[0];
        System.out.println(x);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
[48, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
48
```

The output should contain 0 instead of 48. Please help

Comment: Do you want a `char[]` rather than a `byte[]`?

Comment: I want a 0. I receive 48

Comment: [`String.getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--)  uses the user's default character encoding, which is not what you want except when it is exactly what want. Use one of the other `String.getBytes(xxxx)` with, say, `StandardCharsets.UTF-8`.

Comment: Can you be sure the number is only one decimal digit? Is there some disadvantage to reversing each step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`48` is the ASCII code of `0`

```
 int x=b[0]-48;
```